# TypeScript compiler crashes at checkUnusedClassMembers

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 2.7.1 Compiler crashes with the following message:

```
D:\BitBucket\EA Studio>tsc -p tsconfig.json
C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:59841
                throw e;
                ^

Error: Debug Failure.
    at checkUnusedClassMembers (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35757:38)
    at checkUnusedIdentifiers (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:35643:29)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:37913:21)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:37891:13)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:260:30)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:37957:16)
    at getDiagnostics (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:37934:24)
    at Object.getEmitResolver (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:20122:17)
    at emitWorker (C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:59783:69)
    at C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:59757:66
```

tsconfig.json

```
"target": "es5",
"strict": true,
"pretty": true,
"removeComments": true,
"sourceMap": false,
"strictNullChecks": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noImplicitThis": true
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Found out it works without `"noUnusedLocals": true`.

Comment: That's a bug, you should see if there's an open issue on GitHub about it and if not file one.